# React Redux dispatch action

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm having a dispatch loadMovies using redux,when first time I load the app.
Now when click over a movie,i will be redirected to movieDetails page.

when I redirect back to the movies page(home page) the action will be dispatched again.

How to avoid dispatching each time I redirected to hone page?
How could i fix this issue??

Please help

Comment: It's kind of difficult to diagnose code if we can't see what it's doing. Can you update your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: If you have a thunk that fetches movies then just check if the movies are not already in the state before fetching them. Now your component can dispatch whenever it's mounted but the thunk will decide if it needs to fetch data.

Comment: hi i changed the action as below , added a cache_time_out   in minutes , as for example if this was triggered again, before time out was expired this will not fetch the data again,

Answer (score 0):

````
export const fetchMovies = () => {
 
  return async (dispatch, getState) => {
    try {
      let { lastFetched } = getState().movies;
      let hourDiff = Math.abs(lastFetched - Date.now());
      let minDiff = hourDiff / 60 / 1000; //in minutes

      if (minDiff < CACHE_TIME_OUT) return;

      dispatch(beginDataFitching(true));
      const { data } = await axios.get(
        `${API_URL}/movie/popular?api_key=${API_KEY}&language=en-US&page=150`
      );
      let res = data.results.map((movie) => {
        return {
          id: movie.id,
          image: `${IMAGE_BASE_URL}/${POSTER_SIZE}/${movie.poster_path}`,
          title: movie.title,
          ...movie,
        };
      });

      dispatch(fetchSuccess(res));
    } catch (e) {
      dispatch(fetchFaild(e.message));
    }
  };
}```
````